# jQuery tr.next always returns row at index 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, html-table

I have a HTML table that automatically adds a row when you enter data on the last row.  Because of this automatic generation, the standard tab functionality breaks down.  You can see an example of this table [here](http://home.claygarland.com/invoicing/index.php). As such, I use jQuery to bounce back up to the parent row of the first ant last elements when shift-tab or tab is pressed.  The code is relatively simple. . .

```
$(this).parents('tr').next('tr');
```

No matter what I do, `$(this).parents('tr').index()` is always returning 0.  Thus `next()` always jumps to the second row of the table, even if I tab from the last field on the ninth row.

Any ideas?  Is there a way that I can rebuild the table's tab index after I've added a row, or does anyone know why the row always thinks that it's index is 0?

Answer (score 1):

I could not comment to Sushanth's answer so I'll give my own:

You just need to use:

```
$(this).closest('tr').index()
```

The problem with Shushanth's code is that it is passing to index() a jQuery object which matches all the tr in the table. It would work if it was (subtle difference):

```
$(this).closest('tr').index('#tableid tr')
```

[See my fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/frankfajardo/vGefy/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `index with a specific selector.`

```
$tableRows = $('#tableid tr');

$currRow = $(this).closest('tr');

var index = $currRow.index($tableRows);
```

Comment: Tried it, and every row still thinks that it's the first.  Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Can you create a small fiddle of what you seem to encounter

Comment: I included a link in the post to a temporary server hosting the problem form.  http://home.claygarland.com/invoicing

Comment: @Peter.. But it would be debug thru the code as we won't have any control over ir

Comment: I'll see what I can do, there's a lot of code, and I don't believe I'll be able to grant the necessary database permissions to have access to the remote data.

Comment: Right.. We don't need any data to play with.. Just a dummy sample would suffice